# Linux Kernel: i2c adapters vs i2c devices probe order

Tags: linux, binding, kernel, i2c, probe

i2c client devices need to be probed before i2c adapters, how does Linux kernel handle this probe order ? as far as I know, both have the same probing priority, however, i2c client probe cannot happen if its corresponding device is not created yet by the i2c adapter.

I have looked into I2C subsystem code but does not seem to defer probing if adapter is not yet present.

Comment: How would you probe clients before the adapter is created?